# Element not exists, takes a lot of time to Execute next line of code

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working as Automation Engineer using selenium, I have found one problem with selenium,
If Element is not exists in the HTML page or DOM its take a lot of time to find that element more than 5 min after 5 mins its executes next line of code I want if that element not exists in the page it immediately  go to the next line of code but it takes more time.In Some cases element exists in page so I did if element exist then come this code otherwise go to else code I have a lot of  cases like these so it takes a lot of take to execute complete code,

I tried with all possible ways like list ,`try` and `Catch` but unable to reduce time, Can you give any solution for this in selenium?

Comment: it's not selenium problem driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS); will not wait for the elements

Comment: You didn't post your code or anything... I'm not sure how we're supposed to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your rply For Suppose Sample code  if(driver.findelement(By.xpath("somexpath")) { if element find then code comes here } else { otherwise come into else block } above code problem is if element not present then its takes 5 min after goto next line of code  I need immediate action

Answer (score 0):

When you create your driver define implicit wait

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will try to locate the elements for up to 5 seconds, you can change it to whatever suits you.

Comment: This is very likely what is causing the unwanted delays. He's looking for elements that don't exist so it's automatically applying an implicit wait for each element that isn't found.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer its reduced half the time here  5 means 5 seconds in stop watch its wait 55 sec